# write new row in csv in each iteration for loop

Tags: r

```
for (i in 1:length(mdma4)) 
{
result <- mdma$MRP.Area[grepl(mdma4[i], mdma$Material)] 
result <- unique(result)
result <- rbind(data.frame(as.list(result)))
write.table(result, file = "mrp_area_missing.csv", append = TRUE,sep = ",")
}
```

I need to write csv file
During each iteration of loop, it should add a row into file
The above code, is creating single row file
Please help

Comment: reproducible example please.

Comment: I'd suggest creating a variable in a loop (or using an apply), then writing to file at the end, rather than file writing in a loop. Easier to debug too.

Answer (score 0):

Put the result in a dataframe and write the dataframe outside the loop.
It's much more efficient and way easier.

```
n=length(mdma4)
ncols= 4 # put here number of cols
out <-data.frame(matrix(rep(1,n*ncols),n,ncols))

for (i in 1:n){
    result <- mdma$MRP.Area[grepl(mdma4[i], mdma$Material)] 
    result <- unique(result)
    out[i,]<-result
} 

write.table(out, file = "mrp_area_missing.csv",sep = ",")
```